# Is it possible to use Endeca Guided Selling without Exp manager?

Tags: search, atg, endeca

A basic question on Endeca I suppose. The scenario is we have a commerce website that running on say, ATG Search (or any other search) & we need to move to Endeca. Is it possible to just use the guided selling aspect of Endeca or is it mandatory to use the experience manager also?

A second question, if we have to use experience manager then does it mean that the page layouts of the current site would have to change or can they be retained?

Comment: I assume you mean 'Guided Navigation'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to answer this would be to speak to your Oracle Account Manager as they will be able to confirm whether you have/should license Experience Manager. Considering that, even in the most recent release of Endeca (now called Oracle Guided Navigation) you can download the Tools And Frameworks module without including Experience Manager, you do not have to use Experience Manager.

As far as your second question is concerned, if you did use Experience Manager, you don't have to push all of your page layouts through this. The biggest benefit in using Experience Manager is that it gives you more control over how you merchandise the different levels in your taxonomy but you can also do that manually.

Comment: would you mind giving me a brief example of your answer to the second question.

Comment: It depends, even though we have Experience Manager, our Product Detail Pages are 90% rendered by ATG. We simply call the `InvokeAssemblerDroplet` with a few parameters to render the breadcrumbs. On the flip side, without Experience Manager, you can get a mapping of the Category Ids to the Dimension Values from the `state` folder in Endeca, load this manually into your repository and then do a lookup from the Dimension Value to the ATG Category Id. Then simply add your merchandising rules in the BCC for the specific category. It will work but I'm not saying its a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to just use the guided selling aspect of Endeca

**Yes.** (Tools And Frameworks comes in two flavors.  One, *with* Experience Manager, and another one *without* Experience Manager, which is also called as *Guided Search*).  Use of Experience Manager is NOT mandatory.

> If we have to use experience manager then does it mean that the page
>   layouts of the current site would have to change or can they be
>   retained?

**Yes**, the page layouts of the current site should be adjusted.